# Keep getting an error for my program

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am trying to add a Salesperson to my database using `JDBC`, but for some reason my code produces an error with the date format in the Java code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procAddSalesPeople] 
@ID int, 
@FirstName varchar(25),
@LastName varchar(25),
@StartDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO SalesPeople(ID, FirstName, LastName, StartDate) 
VALUES (@ID, @FirstName, @Lastname, @StartDate)
END

//Test the addSalesPerson() method

System.out.println("Testing addSalePeople() stored procedure");
SalesPeople sp = new SalesPeople( 7,"Jim", "Ike", Date.valueOf("10-10-1991")); 
dbc.addSalesPeople(sp);
```

Below is the error:

Testing `addSalePeople()` stored procedure

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at   java.sql.Date.valueOf(Unknown Source) at   database.framework.StoredProcedureTester.initialize(StoredProcedureTester.java:57) at   database.framework.StoredProcedureTester.main(StoredProcedureTester.java:112)

Comment: You need to write `Date.valueOf("1991-10-10")` - the format must be year-month-day.  I consider this a typo, which is why I VTC'ed it instead of giving an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but when I tried it, it gives an error stating   "Error converting data type nvarchar to date."

Comment: OK, well that error is not in the code you've shown.  You need to show us the JDBC code where you actually call the stored procedure.